# Nest can't resolve dependencies (RoleRepository, EntitlementService, ?) Please make sure Object at index [2] is available in the RolesModule context

Tags: javascript, import, nestjs, typeorm

I have a Company module and roles module. I am trying to use a function of company service in roles service for that I have imported companyService in rolesService but I am getting the following errors.

roles.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class RolesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Role)
    private rolesRepository: Repository<Role>,
    private entitlementService: EntitlementService,
    private companyService: CompanyService,
  ) {}

 async getEntitlementList(getEntitlementDto: GetEntitlementDto) {
   const role: Role = await this.findOne(getEntitlementDto.roleId);
     const company: Company = await this.companyService.findOne(
       getEntitlementDto.companyId,
     );
     const companyRole = this.companyService.validateCompanyRole(role, company);
     let entitlements: Entitlement[];

     if (companyRole) {
       entitlements = role.entitlements;
     }

     return entitlements;
   }
```

roles.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Role]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Company]),
    forwardRef(() => EntitlementModule),
    forwardRef(() => CompanyModule),
  ],
  controllers: [RolesController],
  providers: [RolesService, CompanyService],
  exports: [RolesService],
})
export class RolesModule {}
```

I have included company module,service and entity in all way possible. I dont understand where I am missing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you exported the `CompanyService` form the `CompanyModule`? If not please do so.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    // your imports
  ],
  controllers: [// your controllers],
  providers: [// your services],
  exports: [CompanyService], // export it 
})
export class CompanyModule {}
```

As you have imported the `CompanyModule` in the `RoleModule` you do not need to include the `CompanyService` in the providers array in `RoleModule`.